# Check if a string contains multiple occurrences of a character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to make sure a string has the format of an ip address.  I don't need anything too specific.  I just want to check if there are three `.` in the string.  I can check if there is one `.` in there like this:

```
 str.include? '.'
```

But how can I check for multiple `.`?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Ruby has a built in [`IPAddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class for dealing with IP addresses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String has a [`.count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-count) method which takes in a character.

```
str.count('.') == 3
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are looking to match an IP address, [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) has an example of capturing an IP using Regular Expressions.

```
if possible_ip_address.match(%r{\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b})
  # code here...
end
```

This will capture addresses that aren't valid (such as 999.999.0.1) but it will prevent false positives like

```
"not.real.ip.address".count('.') == 3 #=> true
```

Comment: +1 for showing a solution, the pitfall to it, and a recommended approach. That doesn't just hand them a fish, it teaches them how to and why.

Answer (score 7):

[String#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-count) counts the number of occurrences of each character in its argument:

```
"127.0.0.1".count('.')
# => 3
```

So to answer your question literally,

```
"127.0.0.1".count('.') == 3
# => true
```

In reality, I'd be hard-pressed to consider that even a poor IP address validator.  I'd probably do something like this:

```
require 'ipaddr'

def validateIP(s)
  !!IPAddr.new(s) rescue false
end

validateIP('127.0.0.1')
# => true
validateIP('999.0.0.1')
# => false
```

Comment: Your `validateIP` method is similar to some code I wrote for an in-house tool. It can be simplified: `def validate_ip(s) !!IPAddr.new(s) rescue false; end`. I don't normally like in-line `rescue`, but it's OK in this case because we want to know two things, is it valid or not.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, that is much simpler.  In-line `rescue` is one of those things I understand when I see but never think to use in my own code.  It definitely makes things simpler here.  Thanks!

Comment: Inline `rescue` is a very sharp two-edged sword. It can cover exceptions you don't intend for it to do, so you have to use it very carefully, but, when used correctly it can really be useful. Just don't cut your finger off. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those "don't reinvent a working wheel" cases.

Ruby comes with the [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class, which is used to manipulate IP addresses. Regular expressions are included in the class that are used to parse the target IP string into octets. Reuse `IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE`:

```
require 'ipaddr'
IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE
=> /
    \A
    (\d+) \. (\d+) \. (\d+) \. (\d+)
    \z
  /x
```

This pattern matches against an entire string because of `\A` and `\z`. Here are some range tests:

```
'one.two.three.four'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> nil
'1.2.3.4'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> "1.2.3.4"
'foo 1.2.3.4 bar'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> nil
'128.255.255.255'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> "128.255.255.255"
'999.999.999.999'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> "999.999.999.999"
'0000.0000.0000.0000'[IPAddr::RE_IPV4ADDRLIKE]
=> "0000.0000.0000.0000"
```

If, as you work with IP addresses, you need more power, check out the [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem. It's very nice.

---

To know if you've actually received a *valid* IP address, see the answer by @DarshanComputing.